# emacs macro: A sentence on each line

Tags: emacs

It is not a a latex question, rather an emacs one but related to latex!

Does anyone know of a macro or ... that makes the following formatting possible:
I want each line to contain only a single sentence.

It is useful in latex, in order to keeps diffing easier, since changes to a sentence will not cascade a change to the following line and hence easier diff !!

Thanks!

Comment: Do the answers at "[How do I get Emacs to fill sentences, but not paragraphs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539984/how-do-i-get-emacs-to-fill-sentences-but-not-paragraphs)" work?

Comment: seems quite relevant. I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it seems to have been answered on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/539984/1443496).

Comment: Sure, feel free to close it. I have moved to vim anyway :D